# How to display two data table in one php?? But it ony come out a table record

Tags: php

I'm trying to put two table record into one PHP, but it only views one of the records when including both PHP file?
another file when echo will become an undefined index.
**Main.php**

```
<?php 
include"Location.php";
include"Fullname.php";
 ?>
<html>
<head>
<table id ="table">
<tr>
<th>Customer Name</th>
<th>Location From</th>
<th>Location To</th>
<th>Departure Date</th>
<th>Return Date</th>
<th>Travel</th>
</tr>
<?php
if(isset($result ) && !empty($result )){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "
    <tr>
    <td>{$row['Fullname']}</td>}}
    <td>{$row['LocationFrom']}</td>
    <td>{$row['LocationTo']}</td>
    </tr>\n";
    }
}
 ?>
 </table>   
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Location.php**

```
<?php

$user=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'user');
$fn=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'fn');
$email=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email');
$ps=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'ps');
$rps=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'rps');
$from=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'from');
$to=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'to');
$departure=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'departure');
$return=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'return');
$flight=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'flight');

$servername="localhost";
$dbusername="root";
$dbpassword="";     
$dbname="register";


$conn=new mysqli($servername,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

die('Connection Error('. mysqli_connect_errno() .')'. mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{

$sql = "SELECT * FROM booking";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

**Fullname.php**

```
<?php

$user=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'user');
$fn=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'fn');
$email=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email');
$ps=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'ps');
$rps=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'rps');
$from=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'from');
$to=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'to');
$departure=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'departure');
$return=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'return');
$flight=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'flight');

$servername="localhost";
$dbusername="root";
$dbpassword="";     
$dbname="register";


 $conn=new mysqli($servername,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);

 if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

die('Connection Error('. mysqli_connect_errno() .')'. mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{

$sql = "SELECT Fullname FROM useraccount";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


mysqli_close($conn);
 }
?>
```

Why it comes out the data only one table?? When have include "FullName.php" and included "Location.php", it only displays fullname.php data only. 
[Picture with only one record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFjB6.png)

Comment: Because you set results in one variable name! ‘$result’, add to this variable, name of the table and you are good to go

Comment: can u show me how to done this

Comment: Just set result from location table to $result_location, and result from Fullname to $result_fullname

Comment: change already, then in main php the $result change to wht?

Answer (score 0):

It is only showing one table because you are overridding the value. 
for example, This is what you are doing
**file1.php**

```
a = 3
```

**file2.php**

```
a = 4
```

So when you include both files. **file2.php** will override the value of **file1.php**
so what you need to do is set **file2.php**'s a variable to a different name. So ...

```
b = 4
```

And now you will have both values 3 and 4 just in different variables.
In your case just do this

**Main.php**

```
<?php 
result = []
include"Location.php";
include"Fullname.php";
 ?>
<html>
<head>
<table id ="table">
<tr>
<th>Customer Name</th>
<th>Location From</th>
<th>Location To</th>
<th>Departure Date</th>
<th>Return Date</th>
<th>Travel</th>
</tr>
<?php
if(isset($result ) && !empty($result )){
    while($location_row = $result[0]->fetch_assoc() and $fullname_row = $result[1]->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "
    <tr>
    <td>{$fullname_row['Fullname']}</td>}}
    <td>{$location_row['LocationFrom']}</td>
    <td>{$location_row['LocationTo']}</td>
    </tr>\n";
    }
}
 ?>
 </table>   
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Location.php**

```
<?php

$user=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'user');
$fn=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'fn');
$email=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email');
$ps=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'ps');
$rps=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'rps');
$from=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'from');
$to=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'to');
$departure=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'departure');
$return=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'return');
$flight=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'flight');

$servername="localhost";
$dbusername="root";
$dbpassword="";     
$dbname="register";


$conn=new mysqli($servername,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

die('Connection Error('. mysqli_connect_errno() .')'. mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{

$sql = "SELECT * FROM booking";
array_push($result, mysqli_query($conn,$sql));



mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

**Fullname.php**

```
<?php

$user=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'user');
$fn=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'fn');
$email=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email');
$ps=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'ps');
$rps=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'rps');
$from=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'from');
$to=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'to');
$departure=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'departure');
$return=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'return');
$flight=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'flight');

$servername="localhost";
$dbusername="root";
$dbpassword="";     
$dbname="register";


 $conn=new mysqli($servername,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);

 if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

die('Connection Error('. mysqli_connect_errno() .')'. mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{

$sql = "SELECT Fullname FROM useraccount";
 array_push($result, mysqli_query($conn,$sql));


mysqli_close($conn);
 }
?>
```

Basically I fixed the second problem by looping through the rows of both location and full name at the same time. So every row in full name database is associated with the row in location that has the same index. It is a bad way to structure you database, but I assume you are new so it works for your needs

Comment: Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lesson php\assignment\Location.php on line 29
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lesson php\assignment\Location.php on line 29

Comment: it say like this ohh

Comment: so wht should i do

Comment: did it work. if it did please, accept it as the answer

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Fullname in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lesson php\assignment\adminMenu.php on line 89

Comment: Cannot leh, it pop out his for others also

Comment: that error has nothing to do with my code tho. That error was already there before. Can you update you question and add, adminMenu.php

Comment: adminMenu.php is main.php

Comment: well which line is 89

Comment: $row['Fullname']; for LocationFrom and others also undefined index

Comment: oh ok I see what you are trying to do. I dont know why you are splitting them into 2 files to achieve that. but give me a bit to whipe something up

Comment: Sorry boss fell asleep.